# Jquery cycle overflow problem

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, cycle

In the jquery.cycle.js file, there is the following code:

```
$.fn.cycle.transitions.scrollRight = function($cont, $slides, opts) {
   $cont.css('overflow','hidden');
   opts.before.push($.fn.cycle.commonReset);
   var w = $cont.width();
   opts.cssFirst = { left: 0 };
   opts.cssBefore= { left: -w, top: 0 };
   opts.animIn    = { left: 0 };
   opts.animOut  = { left: w };
};
```

I'm trying to get only the y-overflow to be hidden, but changing:

```
$cont.css('overflow','hidden');
```

To:

```
$cont.css('overflow','visible');
```

Changes both the y and x overflow. Is there any way to change only the x or y overflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works in Firefox and IE, but I'm not sure if it is a valid css:

```
$cont.css('overflow-y','hidden');
$cont.css('overflow-x','scroll');
```

Comment: It's a part of the CSS3 specification, but it's supported by most browsers.. http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-box/#overflow

Comment: What do you write to get rid of the scrollbars?

Comment: sorry, just saw your comment. You could just replace scroll with visible if you want.